# npx create-react-app not completing its job(windows)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to start with react and I am following the steps.
it says :

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@3.32.0 postinstall C:\Users\Prabhat\Sandbox\react\r-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.32.0 postinstall C:\Users\Prabhat\Sandbox\react\r-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.2.0
+ react-scripts@5.0.1
+ react-dom@18.2.0
+ react@18.2.0
added 1441 packages from 629 contributors in 206.238s

232 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

however every time I am stuck with a response like this below image :

I did follow these steps but it is not going forward:

```
1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
This is the npm command to uninstall your global installation of create-react-app. Theoretically, when this removes the global install, you should be able to run npx create-react-app my-app. This, however, did not work for me.

2. yarn global remove create-react-app
This is basically the yarn version of what is done in the previous method. I wasn’t using yarn, so this method didn’t apply to me.

3. npm update npx
This simple line is actually the only thing that worked for me. After running npm update npx, I ran the original npx create-react-app my-app and it worked like a charm. You’d be surprised by how…
```

Comment: Could you include the image you're referring to ?

Comment: not able to add image but my problem is I am not finding the "start" command in package.json and hence I am not able to run the "npm start" to begin with the app

Answer (score 0):

This may be cache issue.For this run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

If the issue still persisits then the best way is to restart your laptop.